# Downloading certain apps on CM 12.1/13 causes it to bootloop

Tags: boot-loop

I flashed Cyanogenmod 12.1 on my 1st Gen Motorola Moto G (aka. Falcon) successfully through TWRP. Afterwards, I flashed gapps on my device (from OpenGApps.org) successfully. I set up my google account on it and everything with no problems.

However, after I had started downloading WhatsApp on my device, it crashed and restarted. Instead of giving the the "Warning: Bootloader Unlocked" message, it cut straight to the Cyanogenmod logo and started bootlooping. This would stop if I went into TWRP's File Manager, and deleted the files for the app in `/data` (or if I did a factory reset, which would also delete those files).

This had happened to me multiple times with multiple apps with both versions 12.1 and 13 of Cyanogenmod. Is there a way for me to have these apps on my device without it bootlooping?

Comment: Last friday WhatsApp updated on my Redmi Note 4 running LineageOS 13 and it crashed everything I had running in the background and then it just bootlooped... Something is wrong with WhatsApp. :s

Answer (score 0):

In my case (Nexus 4 (Mako)), I have it running only on CM 10. WhatsApp then started to cause the boot loop on CM >= 11. Since I need a custom ROM for 4.4+/KitKat or up, I ended up in flashing LineageOS 14.1 (Nougat) and so far it's been working fine for me. (ツ)